# Python Script that opens a web window at a specific time

Tags: python, time, automation

I am trying to code a script in Python that will take a time input from the user and then open a web page every day at that time. For example: I run the program and say, "open [page] at [time]" ideally it would store this in a document in the directory so the program could be closed when not needed and maintain times. The program would then wait until the specified time and then open a web page that was specified earlier at that time.
I know this is probably super easy but I fully acknowledge I'm a noob. Thanks for not rubbing it in.

Any help would be great! Thanks!
*-Meteor*

Answer (score 0):

Just write a script to open a webpage using python. Then you can schedule it to run at a specific time using crontab.

Comment: I got the webpage script down already. Isn’t crontab Linux only or am I wrong? I would like to be able to distribute this as a click to run program. Mabye a python module that I could use?